# In emacs how do you find a function's documentation in info

Tags: emacs, help-files

Doing C-h f looks up the help for a function in emacs, and by clicking the link in the help box I can go to the source.

Is there a way to go from the function help window to info, searching specifically for the chapter that function is documented in.

Or if not a way to quickly search info for the selected function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `Info-goto-emacs-command-node`, bound to `C-h F`. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any integration between the two different forms of documentation.

This is a bit rough, but drop this in your `.emacs` file and from the `C-h f` documentation for a function you'll be able to hit `i` ("info") to jump to the corresponding `C-h F` documentation.

```
(defun Info-goto-from-command-help ()
  "Go to the Info node in the Emacs manual for the command
currently being viewed in `help-mode'."
  (interactive)
  (when (eq 'describe-function (car help-xref-stack-item))
    (Info-goto-emacs-command-node (cadr help-xref-stack-item))))

(define-key help-mode-map "i" 'Info-goto-from-command-help)
```

Comment: That's neat thanks! I add this condition to the when ... (commandp (cadr help-xref-stack-item))) because it wasn't working for me initially and I didn't realize that it works only for interactive commands.

Comment: Original question asked for *function* definition.  Info-goto-emacs-command-node works only for, you guessed it, commands.